# Automation between containers of different objects with copy assign

Tags: c++, containers, copy-constructor, copy-assignment

I have a sparse vector of type `std::vector<SparseElement<T,I>>` where SparseElement is:

```
template<typename T, typename I = unsigned int>
struct SparseElement
{
    I index;
    T value;
    //............
    SparseElement &operator=(const std::pair<I,T> &pair);
 }
```

Because I am using for filling the sparse vector a `std::map<I,T>` which has as elements `std::pair<I,T>`, I want a solution on this without changing the 'index' and 'value' members of SparseElement:

```
std::pair<I,T> a;
SparseElement<T,I> b;
b = a; // This is OK!
a = b; // Is there a solution on this problem?
// on containers:
std::vector<SparseElement<T,I>> vec;
std::map<I,T> m(vec.begin(), vec.end()); // Not working.
vec.assign(m.begin(), m.end()); // Working.
```

Comment: `a = b;` maybe `template<class I, class T> std::pair<I,T>& operator=(pair<I,T> lhs, SparseElement<T, I> const & SE);` as a free function.

Comment: @RedX - nope, I fell for that, too. `operator=` must be a non-static member function, defined by the standard.

Comment: @KirilKirov Dang, that would have been nice if possible.

Comment: Then maybe add member `operator std::pair<I,T>()` conversion member to your SparseElement class.

Comment: @RedX - nice, that should work.

Answer (score 0):

Rewriting the answer to help the community

```
template<typename T, typename I = unsigned int>
struct SparseElement
{
    //..........
    I index;                //!< Index of element in vector
    T value;                //!< Value of element
    //..........
    //! Template copy constructor from a different type of \p std::pair
    //! This is useful for conversion from MapVector to SparseVector
    template<typename T2, typename I2>
    SparseElement(const std::pair<I2,T2> &s) : index(s.first), value(s.second) {}
    //..........
    //! Template copy assign from a different type of \p std::pair
    //! This is useful for conversion from MapVector to SparseVector
    template<typename T2, typename I2>
    SparseElement &operator=(const std::pair<I2,T2> &s) { index = s.first; value = s.second; return *this; }

    //! Implicit conversion from SparseElement to a \p std::pair
    //! This is useful for conversion from SparseVector to MapVector
    operator std::pair<const I,T>() { return std::pair<const I,T>(index, value); }
};
```